# Design question on web application

Tags: java, jquery

I want to design a web application running inside tomcat to do interact with the backend database. What's the framework you could recommend to adopt? Spring MVC or Struts? Also, which works better with JQuery if needing Javascript in the frontend. Also, heard about Tapestry/ Webworks, how is that fit into the role?

Comment: Just try to listening some overall suggestions, subjective is OK.

Comment: Actually, subjective is not okay on StackOverflow. See [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: There are always many ways to solve a problem. How you avoid subjective?

Comment: There are lots of resources all over the Internet on how to ask good questions. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question is a good place to start, and specifically geared towards asking question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Too wide a topic. No real answer without knowing which way you work. And combining several questions into one question.

Comment: For example, you can start by explaining what are your website requirements and asking about how each framework solves the problem in hand. BTW, it may very well be that after thinking about your question you may end up answering it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC

Has a big community and is used by any big applications like hybris.

In my opinion: Struts is out of date.

Spring MVC is an Model View Controller. It has no problem with jQuery, AJAX an so on.